# Java- can't open pom.xml (maven) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I installed eclipse from ubuntu software and java in terminal with:

```
 sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

I could not add maven from eclipse until I did not run eclipse with root. 
I can convert project to maven now but this is what I get when I do:

> Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated.
>   This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the
>   editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

Things I did:

1. delete workspace and create a new one - still the same,
2. start eclipse with -clean  - still the same,
3. install some other m2e plugins - telling me I have the latest version
4. uninstall eclipse and install it from terminal - still the same.

My Eclipse version is 3.8.1

Comment: Well, I had some problems with open-jdk and eclipse. When I switched to oracle-jdk I got rid of some strange problems. So you may give this a try - but I am not sure, if this is related to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse editor won't open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436403/eclipse-editor-wont-open)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse in ubuntu software center is outdated. I installed last version from official eclipse website and it's working.